# addObserver selector function is never called in embedded view controller (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I have my storyboard set up with a main `ViewController`and a `NavigationController` with a secondary `ViewController` embedded. The main `ViewController` and `NavigationController` are connected with a show segue that is triggered on a button press. The photo attached shows my storyboard.

[image: Picture of my storyboard]

When the button is clicked, the label in `LabelViewController` should change, and the show segue should trigger and show the `NavigationViewController` (with `LabelViewController` embedded). The last half works, and the `NavigationViewController` is shown, but the label's value never changes.

To change the label's value, I am using `NotificationCenter`'s `addObserver` and `post`. While there are other methods, I need to use `NotificationCenter` to pass through data (`userData`).

### Code

Inside of the first `ViewController` I have this single line of code inside of an `IBAction` that triggers on the button's press.

`NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "changeLabelValue"), object: nil, userInfo: ["labelValue": "Changed value"])`

Then, inside of `LabelViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` I have another line of code for the observer.

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeLabelValue(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "changeLabelValue"), object: nil)`

The selector function, `changeLabelValue` looks like this.

```
func changeLabelValue(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    label.text = notification.userInfo?["value"] as? String
}
```

### Problem

As said above, the show segue triggers and I am shown the `NavigationViewController`, but the selector function (`changeLabelValue`) inside of `LabelViewController` never gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is never called because it is only resisted to receive function calls in the second view controller's `viewDidLoad`. However, when you press your button in your first view controller, your second view controller hasn't been loaded.

To correctly pass data, you need to use `prepareForSegue`. So in your first view controller, you need to first check if your segue destination is an `UINavigationController` because your second view controller is embedded inside. If so, check if the `topViewController` of your navigation controller is your `SecondViewController`. If both are true, pass the data and it will be available in `viewDidLoad` section of your `SecondViewController`. Sample code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
        if let secondViewControoler = destinationViewController.topViewController as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewControoler.yourProperty = self.yourLabel.text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

The following is not valid in Swift 3. Check out @FangmingNing's answer.

---

You would need to add `@objc` to your `changeLabelValue` function as the observer must inherit from an Objective-C NSObject.

```
@objc func changeLabelValue(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    label.text = notification.userInfo?["value"] as? String
}
```

Comment: In Swift3. `NotificationCenter.defaul` does not need a `@objc` prefix

Comment: Just checked, second that. Thanks.